# In R, how do I compute factors' percentage given on different variable?

Tags: r, percentage

I am trying to compute percentage of factors in a variable, and want to make that percentage conditional on other variable.

For example, I have data like this.

```
State Ideology
CO    Liberal
CO    Liberal
CO    Liberal
CO    Conservative
CO    Conservative
CO    Independent
DC    Independent
DC    Conservative
DC    Liberal
```

I am trying to find the percentage of each Liberal, Conservative, and Independent on each state.

I tried to use ddply like

```
liberal_per<-ddply(data,.(State), summarize,total=table(Ideology)[1]/sum(Ideology))
```

But it doesn't work. How should I try to find percentage of each factor given on State?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want the row percentages of a table with "State" defining the rows? Wouldn't this just be: `100*round( with( data, prop.table( table(State, Ideology) , 1), 2)` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `State` comes first in the data frame, `table` will use that as the row ID.  Thus, you can divide the results of `table` by the row sums to get ratios, or scale to percentage.

The table:

```
> table(x)
     Ideology
State Conservative Independent Liberal
   CO            2           1       3
   DC            1           1       1
```

Using `prop.table` to do the scaling, to get values per-state:

```
> prop.table(table(x), 1)
     Ideology
State Conservative Independent   Liberal
   CO    0.3333333   0.1666667 0.5000000
   DC    0.3333333   0.3333333 0.3333333
```

This is equivalent to `table(x)/rowSums(table(x))`

You can multiply by 100 to get percent values if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your `ddply` code to:

```
 ddply(data,.(State), 
    function(x) with(x,
      data.frame(100*round(table(Ideology)/length(Ideology),2))))

 #    State     Ideology Freq
 #1    CO Conservative   33
 #2    CO  Independent   17
 #3    CO      Liberal   50
 #4    DC Conservative   33
 #5    DC  Independent   33
 #6    DC      Liberal   33
```